CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE with REGEXP_REPLACE and LOCATE not giving the correct result
I have a table with a column named tags. In this column, I have a comma-separated list like отказвам резервацията, отмяна на резервацията, etc.
My query looks like that:
SELECT * FROM products
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(CONCAT('["', REGEXP_REPLACE(tags, ', *', '","'), '"]'),
  '$[*]' COLUMNS(tag VARCHAR(20) PATH '$')
) AS j
WHERE LOCATE(j.tag, 'отказвам резервацията');

In the example in the dbfiddle I have two records with one keyword.
INSERT INTO products VALUES
('отказвам резервацията'),('резервация');

However, when I try to locate отказвам резервацията it matches the record with the word резервация
EXAMPLE: https://dbfiddle.uk/52713UfH
Any ideas about what might be wrong?

when I try to locate отказвам резервацията it matches the record with the word резервация See the difference between LOCATE() and INSTR().

You get short varchar(20) for json_table.
Try varchar(120) or other value, sufficient for column tags.  Otherwise, JSON_TABLE will return a null for 'отказвам резервацията'.
SELECT * FROM products
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(CONCAT('["', REGEXP_REPLACE(tags, ', *', '","'), '"]'),
  '$[*]' COLUMNS(tag VARCHAR(120) PATH '$')
) AS j
WHERE LOCATE('отказвам резервацията',j.tag)>0;

And see LOCATE parameters.

indeed that was the problem. Using varchar(200) did fix the problem. Thanks!
